# Lagrange method over two constraints

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, lagrange-multiplier

plane $x+y-z=-2$ intersects $z^2=x^2+y^2$

I need to use Lagrange multipliers to determine the point of intersection which is the closest to the origin.

As far as I understand, to use Lagrange I need a function $f(x,y,z)$ so that:
$$f(x,y,z)=\lambda G(x,y,z)+\mu F(x,y,z)$$

But what function $f$ should I use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ assuming that you are talking about the Euclidean minimum distance

Here you have two constraints, that means two Lagrangian multipliers namely

$\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ for the constraints $x+y-z+2=0$ and $x^2+y^2-z^2=0$. One can write them all as

$$\mathcal{L}(x,y,z,\lambda_1,\lambda_2)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}+\lambda_1(x+y-z+2)+\lambda_1(x^2+y^2-z^2)$$

Comment: Oh, the distance function. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should solve the problem

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\min \hspace{3mm} x^2 +y^2 +z^2 \\
s.t. \hspace{3mm} x+y -z +2 =0 \\
\hspace{8mm} x^2+y^2-z^2 = 0. \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}

The lagrangian function is given by

$$\mathcal{L} = x^2 +y^2 +z^2 + \lambda (x+y -z +2)+\mu (x^2+y^2-z^2).$$ Hence,

$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x} = 2x +\lambda + 2x\mu= 0 $$

$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y} = 2y +\lambda + 2y\mu= 0$$

$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial z} = 2z -\lambda - 2z\mu= 0 .$$

Now, I think you can solve this system.